# Table will not print with background or type colors

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, printing

I have the "print background colors and images" checked in the print dialogue of my browser. I have tried this in all three major browsers. I can go to any page and it will show the text and cell colors but my own website refuses to show the colors when printing. This is a rails app using bootstrap 2.3.2 and bootswatch for colors. I have a "printable" version of my page with the header:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

I have tried replacing 'all' with 'screen' (still looks correct when the page load but won't print correctly).

Here is my page as it looks:

[image: table]

Here is the print dialogue:

[image: print dialogue]

Here is the PDF produced by "save as PDF":

[image: table pdf]

Here is the dialogue for a page from Stack Overflow in the same browser when I print it:

[image: stack overflow page dialogue]

And here is the pdf produced by the "save as PDF"

[image: stack overflow pdf]

I am on OS X 10.10 and am getting the exact same results in every browser. I have tried setting the "all" in the stylesheet link to "print" but then it doesn't have a stylesheet to refer to, so it removes all styling before going to the print dialogue. If you notice it IS using the css styling for my table in the printed PDF. But it strips out any color info. I'm really stumped by this, have searched quite a bit but only find pages telling you to check the "print backgrounds" checkbox, which I have already done. Why isn't the color even making it to the print dialogue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Bootstrap contains code that makes the background transparent. Try adding !important to your declarations for your background colors and see if that helps you.

Edit:

For example, if you declare the background for it with:

```
th{background:#HEX}
```

then switch it to:

```
th{background:#HEX !important}
```

Replacing th with whatever element you are applying the style to, and #HEX with your colors.

Also note that you need to declare it after the Bootstrap declaration.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I thought it had to be something with bootstrap. So instead of hunting down every reference I need to change, I made a print.css.scss style sheet and use that since this is a "printable" version of the normal page. I copied the base bootstrap.css.min file into my print.css.scss file and removed the entries in ` @media print {
    * {
      color: #000 !important; 
      text-shadow: none !important; 
      background: transparent !important; 
      box-shadow: none !important; 
    }` so it's just `@media print {
    * { }`...

Comment: Great, that also works! I didn't know if you had just one or two places to update it, but of course if you had a lot, your solution works great as well! Glad it helped!

Comment: So you know more about CSS than I do, could I just have copied the `@media print{`... section to my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss , adjusted it how I wanted, and it would override the previous code in the bootstrap base files?

Comment: If copying the `@media print { * { }}` section to another file worked, then I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work, as long as it is declared after the Bootstrap declaration, which since your file is called bootstrap_and_overrides, I'm guessing it is. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: It didn't work, but maybe because the override is additive but not subtractive? I actually like the fact that I've got it in it's own stylesheet that just lives in the `vendor/assets/stylesheets` folder of my app and I can just call it for the printable version of my report pages.

Comment: Then I would stick with that. I'm not that familiar with RoR apps, more of a PHP guy myself, so I may have misunderstood how your stylesheets are called, and what order. But just to make sure, having it in that separate print.css file did solve the issue for you, correct?

Comment: Yes, 100%. Allowed me to have the report printable page still have the table that was sortable via the JS table sorter and retain all of my color marking for the inventory levels. It still cleared the header row cell color, but that is not important for the report, just the marker colors around the numbers.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. :)